# Is it possible to add consumers to MassTransit's Mediator after its creation?

Tags: masstransit

I noticed that consumers receive messages when they are added as follows:

```
var mediator = Bus.Factory.CreateMediator(conf =>
{
  conf.Consumer<OrderAddedConsumer>();
});
```

Messages are not received when consumers ared added as follows:

```
var mediator = Bus.Factory.CreateMediator(conf => { });
mediator.Context.ConnectConsumer<OrderAddedConsumer>();
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Consumers should be added as shown in the first example you gave, which is described in the documentation.

```
var mediator = Bus.Factory.CreateMediator(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Consumer<OrderAddedConsumer>();
});
```

I'm not sure what is happening in the `mediator.Context` version, I'm not sure where you were able to access that property. However that is exposed, it isn't meant to be used to connect consumers.

Comment: Too bad. I was expecting the mediator to allow consumers that come and go. That would be the case in a chat application, which is a classic example for the pattern.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source of a classic example of the pattern? For chat, I'd use SignalR.

Comment: Here are just some examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern,
https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/behavioral/mediator-pattern/, https://books.google.fr/books?id=pD2XMZLGUAYC&lpg=PA205&ots=vcf1_2xvbA&dq=mediator%20pattern%20chat&hl=fr&pg=PA205#v=onepage&q=mediator%20pattern%20chat&f=false